# Complex math-curves

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $y$ be the curve in $X$ defined by

$\displaystyle y(m)=\left(\frac{m^3}{3}\right)-m+\left(im^2\right)$, $m \in [-2,2]$

a)Let $\,f(z) = -iz\,$. Compute integral $\,(y) f(z)dz\,$

b)Calculate the length of $y$

My answer for (b):

The length of $\,C(t)\,$ is given by the usual expression for arc lengths. Defining the real part $\,x = t^3/3 - t\,$ and imaginary part $\,y = t^2\,$ ,

$$S = \int\limits_{-2}^2[(dx)^2+(dy)^2]^{1/2} =\int\limits_{-2}^2[(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2]^{1/2}dt =$$

$$\int\limits_{-2}^2 [(t^2-1)^2+(2t)^2]^{1/2}dt = \int\limits_{-2}^2(t^2+1)dt = 2t^3 + t$$

The answer I get is $S = 32\,$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I made some change to get you going. Regards

Comment: What did you mean by "integral (y)f(z) dz"?

Comment: integral (y), so y is the lower bound

Comment: You should go to the FAQ section and follow there directions to properly write mathematics in this site. It still isn't clear what is that integral you talk about in (a) (for one, what is the upper limit?)...

Comment: there is no upper limit, only the lower limit y

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do part (a) all the same.  Consider

$$\int_C dz \: f(z) = \int_C (\Re{[f(z)]} dx - \Im{[f(z)]} dy) + i \int_C (\Im{[f(z)]} dx + \Re{[f(z)]} dy)$$

where $f(z) = -i z$ and $C$ is the contour defined above.  That is, define

$$x(m) = \frac{1}{3} m^3 - m$$
$$y(m) = m^2$$

$$dx = (m^2-1) dm$$
$$dy = 2m\, dm $$

Note that

$$ \Re{[f(z)]} = y(m)$$
$$ \Im{[f(z)]} = -x(m)$$

Put this all together and integrate between $m \in [-2,2]$.  Viz.

$$\begin{align}&\int_{-2}^2 dm \: [m^2 (m^2-1) + ((m^3/3)-m)(2 m)] + i \int_{-2}^2 dm \: [m^2 \, 2m - ((m^3/3)-m)(m^2-1)]\\ &= \int_{-2}^2 dm \:\left [ \frac{5}{3} m^4 - 3 m^2 \right ] + i \int_{-2}^2 dm \:\left [-\frac{1}{3} m^5 + \frac{4}{3} m^3 +m\right ]\end{align}$$

Note that the imaginary part is zero (why?).  The line integral is then

$$\frac{2}{3} 2^5 - 2 \,( 2^3) = \frac{16}{3}$$